# how to create *.a to *.so in linux user-space?

Tags: linux, gcc, g++, userspace

i done compile file makefile.am and i need shared link for my lib, for example after compile i see `/usr/lib64/libtest.a` but i need `libtest.so` because i need my lib to other C source file,

example :`g++ -llibtest test.c`

i read about this [here](http://docencia.ac.upc.edu/FIB/USO/Bibliografia/unix-c-libraries.html) but i not sure how to work and how to use `ranlib` or `ar`,there is any way for create *.a to *.so?

Comment: Try linking to static library with `g++ -l:libtest.a test.c` or `g++ /usr/lib64/libtest.a test.c`

Comment: not work, again i have `undefined reference`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolve this issue with

```
./configure --disable-shared
```